# how do i transform my code to work in chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

I have a function that works only in IE not in Chrome, because of "Microsoft.XMLDOM" and selectSingleNode (i think), please help me to convert code to Chrome, thanks!

```
var xmlDictionary = null;
```

function onGridMembersSelection(id,xml)
{

```
    var domDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");                  
    domDoc.loadXML(xml);    

                var helpHtml2 = "";
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "Dictionary.xml", true);              
                xmlDictionary = xmlhttp.responseXML;                
                xmlhttp.send();

        helpHtml2 += xmlDictionary.selectSingleNode("Terms/Term[Key='" + domDoc.selectSingleNode("Members/Member/@UName").text + "']/Desc").text;
        alert(helpHtml2);

}
```

Comment: link doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();` instead of: 
 `var domDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");` .
 For other browsers ( Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari ).

And to load XMl File please use:

```
parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
```

as sated in below link..

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp

Please try this as well..

```
                var xmlDictionary = null;    
            function onGridMembersSelection(id,xml) {

            // code for IE
            if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType=="msxml-document")
            {
                var domDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");                  
                domDoc.loadXML(xml);    

                            var helpHtml2 = "";
                            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xmlhttp.open("GET", "Dictionary.xml", true);              
                            xmlDictionary = xmlhttp.responseXML;                
                            xmlhttp.send();

                    helpHtml2 += xmlDictionary.selectSingleNode("Terms/Term[Key='" + domDoc.selectSingleNode("Members/Member/@UName").text + "']/Desc").text;
                    alert(helpHtml2);
            }
            // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
            else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
            {
            var domDoc=new XMLHttpRequest();
             xmlhttp.open("GET", "Dictionary.xml", true);              
             xmlDictionary = xmlhttp.responseXML;             
              xmlhttp.send();   
              xml.evaluate("Terms/Term[Key='" +xml.evaluate("Members/Member/@UName", xmlDictionary , null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null), xmlDictionary , null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).nodeValue;
              helpHtml2 += .text;
              alert(helpHtml2);
            }



            }
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried that, and it doesn't work for some reason, maybe the issue is with xmlDictionary.selectSingleNode and domDoc.selectSingleNode?

Answer (score 0):

Select selectSingleNode using path is not supported by Chrome without some coding unless you select single node only.

| IE SUPPORTED CODE | CHROME SUPPORTED CODE |
| --- | --- |
| var node = root.selectSingleNode (“/ArrayOfWeatherForecast/WeatherForecast/Summary”); | No equivalent, but it can code manually. Refer to funcSelectSingleNode. |
| var nodes = root.selectNodes(“WeatherForecast”); | var nodes = root.getElementsByTagName(“WeatherForecast”); |

```
function funcSelectSingleNode(xmlDoc, elementPath) {   
    if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {         
        var nodes = document.evaluate(elementPath, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        return nodes.iterateNext();
    }
}

//E.g.
var node2 = funcSelectSingleNode(xmlDoc, "/ArrayOfWeatherForecast/WeatherForecast/Summary");
```

Reference:

1. https://mycsharpdeveloper.wordpress.com/2021/08/16/migrating-ie-activexobject-xmlhttp-xmldom-to-chrome/
2. https://forums.asp.net/t/1227814.aspx?xml+SelectNodes+not+working+in+firefox+in+javascript+

*PS: Just replied this old message in case someone still need it.*